# Buttons in custom ActionBar

Tags: android, button, android-actionbar

In my application there is a button in the middle of the `ActionBar`. I am doing this by implementing custom `ActionBar`. It is easy but the problem is that normal `ActionBar Buttons` has their own good properties such as when you long click them they will toast their name etc..

How can I implement my custom button and still have these properties of `ActionBar Items`? Is it even possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Try setting `style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionItem"`

Comment: Ok i was setting ?android:attr/actionButtonStyle
I will definitely try your answer.